# Cookie not saving in safari when adding to home screen

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cookies, safari, jquery-cookie

Hey i'm using the following code to set a cookie and get it :

```
  $.cookie('SimMobileUsername', $('#user_id').val());

  if($.cookie('SimMobileUsername') != "null" && $.cookie('SimMobileUsername') != null); {

    $('#user_id').val($.cookie('SimMobileUsername'));

    }
```

Which works fine but when i add  the webpage to the home screen it dosen't save the cookie.

**Important:**

I have read that safari caches home screen pages, so i tried the following code to refresh the page on 1 time on start but that didn't help either:

```
 var url = window.location.href;
if (url.indexOf('rnd=') == -1) {
    url = (url.indexOf("?") == -1 ? url + "?rnd=" : url + "&rnd=") + Math.random();
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

Any insights on the subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i solved it using localStorage in ios instead of cookie, if someone is to answer the question correctly i'll mark his as the right answer.